# Saccharomyces boulardii with antibiotics. When to take?

Tags: antibiotics, dosage, meal, probiotics, medication-directions

On Saccharomyces boulardii leaflet it's written that it has to be taken on an empty stomach (at least 15 minutes before eating) but if it's to be taken with antibiotics then you should take them together.

Some antibiotics are to be taken on a full stomach, others can be taken even on a empty stomach but it's suggested to take them on a full stomach to avoid irritation (Amoxicillin, to name one)

In such cases where you have to take 
Saccharomyces boulardii with a "full stomach antibiotic" what's the best thing to do? Take them together even though you are on a full stomach or take Saccharomyces boulardii before eating and then antibiotics after?